# Why form redirects to encoded url when having GET params?

Tags: forms, uri, redirection

I have a simple form with 1 select and I want it after the form submit to redirect to the same URL, but with added GET params.

---

So in a form submit I added:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = url(arg(0).'/'.arg(1).'/'.arg(2), array(
  'query' => array(
      'brand' => $state['values']['brand'],
      'categ' => arg(2)
)));
```

Which redirects to wrong encoded url:

> /produkty/vlasy%3Fbrand%3D118%26categ%3D27

---

But It works well when I use drupal goto (this is not recommended):

```
  drupal_goto(arg(0).'/'.arg(1).'/'.arg(2), array(
      'query' => array(
          'brand' => $state['values']['brand'],
          'categ' => arg(2)
  )));
```

> /produkty/vlasy?brand=118&categ=27

---

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust the param value from a string to an array for `$form_state['redirect']`

It is in the documentation for [`drupal_redirect_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7.x)

> $form_state['redirect'] determines where to redirect the user. This can be set either to a string (the path to redirect to), or an array of arguments for drupal_goto().

Example:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  arg(0) . '/' . arg(1) . '/' . arg(2),
  'query' => array(
        'brand' => $form_state['values']['brand'],
        'categ' => arg(2)
  )
);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use urldecode() function.

```
$redirect_url = url(arg(0).'/'.arg(1).'/'.arg(2), array(
  'query' => array(
      'brand' => $state['values']['brand'],
      'categ' => arg(2)
)));
$form_state['redirect'] = urldecode($redirect_url);
```

Output: /produkty/vlasy?brand=118&categ=27

Comment: This will still pass a string to `$form_state['redirect']` which will then be urlencoded by `drupal_goto`